# Why won't Logstash multiline merge lines based on grok'd field?

Tags: elasticsearch, multiline, logstash

I'm trying to get logstash multiline to work with the following test file:

```
val=abc
123 abc
test
```

and using the following config for the filter:

```
filter
{
    if [message] =~ "val"
    {
         match => ["message", "val=%{WORD:calc}"
    }
    multiline
    {
        pattern => [calc]
        what => "next"
    }
}
```

The output shows up as follows (with the other fields stripped):

```
"message" => "val=abc"
"calc" => "abc"
...
"message" => "123 abc"
```

The above lets me know that the grok is matching (hence the "calc" field) but I'm not sure why the multiline isn't merging the the first and 2nd line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean if the `calc` field exist, the first line and the second line will merge to a single envet?

If yes, the following answer can help you. 
Your multiline pattern is incorrect. 
Please refer to this config:

```
input {
    stdin{}
}

filter {
    if [message] =~ "val"
    {
        grok {
            match => ["message", "val=%{WORD:calc}"]
        }
    } 
    multiline
    {
        pattern => "(val)"
        what => "next"
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => "rubydebug"
    }
}
```

The pattern in multiline is when the `message` field has the `val` word, you meet the pattern and it will multiline merge with the second line. In your example you use `[cal]` that's means when the `message` field has the `cal` word, however, there is no any `cal` in the `message` field.

Comment: I was under the impression that `%{WORD:calc}` creates a new field called `calc` and then populates the field with what the `WORD` pattern matched. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes, you are right with the grok filter. But it is not in the multiline pattern. The multiline pattern only see the message field whether have meet the pattern. You can find more information in the logstash page!