# LogStash-Extracting information from different events

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have case where information is being displayed in different lines. These lines are not even consecutive lines. Is there anyway to read these two and combine into single event?

Example log line: where I wanted to gather information from first line and last line into single event

```
07:11:02.002015|OrderId=100 Client=TEST
07:11:02.002016|blah1
07:11:02.002017|blah2
07:11:02.002018|blah3
07:11:02.002019|OrderId=100 Symbol=APPLE Price=99 Quantity=100
```

I wanted to gather all information about OrderId=100 from line1 and line5.

Or can you suggest what is the best way to work on these kind of logs?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652075/kibana-linking-two-independent-events/34652594

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304023/how-to-make-logstash-multiline-filter-merge-lines-based-on-some-dynamic-field-va